# We are facing the formatting issues in ckeditor dev tool

Tags: formatting, ckeditor

We are facing the formatting issues while using the ckeditor dev tools, table styles are not rendering properly.

Comment: styles are not working properly in customized tool in ckeditor

Comment: the html data which was converted from word to html string is not rendering properly in CKEditor devleoper tool